# How to prevent clicks to custom button component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

**tl;dr - How do I get the `click()` handler on the myButton component to honor the disabled state of the button?**

I have a custom button component that's used to componentize buttons of similar look and feel, including text and FA Icons. The button component gets fed certain inputs, including its text and a flag for whether or not its disabled. When disabled, it displays correctly (i.e. dimmed and the no-smoking cursor), but its `click()` handler always receives the click.

I think I know why this is happening, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried declaring an `Output() click = new EventEmitter<any>()` on the button component thinking that somehow Angular would wire it up correctly but that didn't work.

The consumer of my button would do so with something like this:

```
//foo.component.html
...
<my-button
  (click)="saveWidget()"
  [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled"
  type="{{buttonTypes.save}}">
</myButton>
...

//foo.component.ts
import { ButtonTypes } from './myButton';

export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
  buttonTypes = ButtonTypes;

  saveWidget() {
    //do some saving
  }

  get shouldBeDisabled() {
    return true; //Normally a real test in here
  }
  ...
}
```

My problem is that when this button is used, the click handler (i.e. `saveWidget()` on foo.component) is being invoked regardless of the `my-button`'s disabled state.

The button component looks something like this:

```
export enum ButtonTypes {
  add,
  cancel,
  save,
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  template: `<button [type]="tagType"
                [disabled]="disabled"
                [ngClass]="btnClasses">
                  <i *ngIf="hasLeft" class="fa" [ngClass]="iconCls" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                  <span class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">{{text}}</span>
                  <i *ngIf="hasRight" class="fa" [ngClass]="iconCls" aria-hidden="true"></i>
              </button>`
})
export class ButtonComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() disabled = false;
  @Input('type') btnType: ButtonTypes;
  @Input() color?: ButtonColor;
  @Input() size?: ButtonSize;
  ...
}
```

Comment: What does your `@Input()` for custom property `disabled` look like in `ButtonComponent`?

Comment: Also are you aware that add/save/cancel are not types for standard HTML `<button>` elements? [HTML <button> type Attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp). Valid types would be "button", "submit", and "reset".

Comment: updated to include button `@Input`s

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `@HostBinding('class')` and [`:host`-selectors](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/component-styles.html#!#special-selectors) to disable clicks via [`pointer-events: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) based on your `shouldBeDisabled` property:

```
//foo.component.scss

:host(.disabled) {
  // Disable click event.
  pointer-events: none;
}

:host(.enabled) {
  // No customizations.
}

//foo.component.html
...
<my-button
  (click)="saveWidget()"
  [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled"
  type="{{buttonTypes.save}}">
</myButton>
...

//foo.component.ts
import { ButtonTypes } from './myButton';

export class FooComponent implements OnInit {

  @HostBinding('class')
  get hostClass(): string {
    return this.shouldBeDisabled ? 'disabled' : 'enabled';
  }

  get shouldBeDisabled() {
    return true; //Normally a real test in here
  }
  ...
}
```

I found [Learning Angular: Conditionally add styles to an element](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/01/learning-ng2-dynamic-styles/)  to be very useful to work through a similar issue.

Comment: yup, that's the easiest way to do that ! :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And sorry for the late acceptance on this one :)

Comment: working solution, scalable, maintainable 2022 |

ng version 13.10.0

Answer (score 1):

The inner `disabled` state of the `ButtonComponent` will NOT prevent the outer `(click)` attached to the component from firing. You can however prevent a `(click)` from occurring within `ButtonComponent` based on the `@Input disabled: boolean`. Using this in combination with `@Output()` could allow you to listen for child enabled button click events in the parent. This along the same lines as [Parent listens for child event](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-listens-for-child-event) in the Angular documentation.

This solution effectively adds only a few additional lines of code and helps ensure the outer handler is not executed unless the button is enabled and clicked.

**Button Component:**

```
import { Component, EventEmitter, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-button',
  template: `
    <button [type]="type" [disabled]="disabled" (click)="handleClick()">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </button>
  `
})
export class ButtonComponent  {
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
  @Input() type: string;
  @Output() clicked = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  // will not execute if the button is disabled
  handleClick() {
    console.log('ButtonComponent: clicked');
    this.clicked.emit(true);
  }
}
```

**Parent Component:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <app-button
        [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled"
        [type]="'button'"
        (clicked)="saveWidget($event)">ENABLED</app-button>
    <app-button
        [disabled]="shouldBeDisabled"
        [type]="'button'"
        (clicked)="saveWidget($event)">DISABLED</app-button>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  get shouldBeDisabled() { return true; }
  get shouldNotBeDisabled() { return false; }

  saveWidget(emittedValue: boolean) {
    console.log(emittedValue);
    console.log('saveWidget()');
  }
}
```

You can pass whatever you'd need to the parent. In this example it's a `boolean`, but it could be something to help identify the widget or whatever you'd need in your example.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2vlyvy) demonstrating the functionality in action.

Comment: Which bit is the bit that makes the button click not be registered? Struggling to apply this fix as my button still triggers the click method. EDIT: Mine worked once I changed the name of my @Output() emitter from click to clicked

Comment: An actual <button> that is `disabled` will prevent native click events.

Answer (score 0):

What does your button component actually look like? i.e does it receive a `disabled` prop?

In which case, add a `(click)` event to it, and just break if it's disabled.

e.g

```
clickHandler() {
   if(this.disabled) {
      return;
   } else {
      // do something...
   }
}
```

Template

```
<your-button (click)="clickHandler()">button</your-button>
```

Failing that, use `ngClass` to apply a disabled CSS class, and use:

```
pointer-events: none;
```